# cannot open S3 on aws console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I keep running into

```
{
  "errorCode" : "InternalError"
}
```

when I try to open S3 in AWS console.

I tried this in threw browsers: Chrome, Firefox and Safari, also in Incognito mode.
My region is Seoul (ap-northeast-2)

But I checked [AWS Service Health dashboard](https://status.aws.amazon.com/), it shows S3 in Seoul region is operating normally.

Also, I'm able to run AWS-CLI.

How could this be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: There is currently a major S3 outage ongoing in the US East 1 region. The AWS console may have a dependency on that region.

Comment: S3 service status is starting to improve, can check your console again

Comment: @duskwuff Agreed. This is something that AWS needs to do: de-couple all AWS S3 console from us-east-1 region. Let each AWS region to have their own console in their respective regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS S3 is experiencing problems

Check the following page for updates:

https://status.aws.amazon.com/

*Update:
[RESOLVED] Increased Error Rates for Amazon S3